# Victory events not re-rendering chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

I am using Victory for data visualisation in my project. However, while implementing event handlers in my charts, I noticed that while they change the target properties, the charts are never re-rendered so nothing changes.

Below is an example from Victory's [documentation](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-scatter/), which does not work on my machine:

```
<div>
  <h3>Click Me</h3>
  <VictoryScatter
    style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31" } }}
    size={9}
    labels={() => null}
    events={[{
      target: "data",
      eventHandlers: {
        onClick: () => {
          return [
            {
              target: "data",
              mutation: (props) => {
                const fill = props.style && props.style.fill;
                return fill === "black" ? null : { style: { fill: "black" } };
              }
            }, {
              target: "labels",
              mutation: (props) => {
                return props.text === "clicked" ?
                  null : { text: "clicked" };
              }
            }
          ];
        }
      }
    }]}
    data={[{ x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 2, y: 3 },
    { x: 3, y: 5 },
    { x: 4, y: 4 },
    { x: 5, y: 7 }]}
  />
</div>
```

After some debugging, I can confirm that the `data` and `labels` properties of the component are changed as a result of the `onClick` event, but these changes are not actually reflected in the chart. Any solutions?

Comment: Are any of the changed props (data, labels) contained in State? If not, there's no reason they would rerender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is caused by having `<React.StrictMode>` on in the code inside `index.js`. Removing it solves the problem. I am not exactly sure why though!!

Comment: It worked! What made you think that ```<React.StrictMode>``` might be causing the issue though?